# Dev-C++ Save source files with similar names?

Tags: dev-c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm using Dev-C++ compiler to learn my coding but I'm having some trouble saving the source files. If I save a source files with similar names to the first one, it always executes the first one whenever I compile and run it. For example, if I name the first source file Hello World.cpp and the second Hello World Anything.cpp it will always execute the code from the first source file. I either have to quit the program and create a new source file for the second or rename the file to something else like HW Anything.cpp. How do I save the files with similar names? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using spaces in filenames/folders when dealing with Dev-CPP. instead, use underscores _ as a subsitute for spaces or CapitalWords.